# Hyphenated tags not working?

Tags: support

While trying to re-tag [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/30029/80)  I've been unable to remove the tag `kalman` and replace it with `kalman-filters`.  Whenever I try that, I just get left with the tag `kalman`.

The tag `kalman` was merged with the tag `kalman-filters` some time ago... and now it's back for some reason.

Other non-moderator users have edited that question and added a new tag... which is not what is required. We just want to use the hyphenated tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the teacher's lounge:

> If [kalman-filters] is synonymised with [kalman], then when you try to add [kalman-filters] in the tag box, it'll automatically map to [kalman].

So all I had to do was to check [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) and delete the synonym.